# How many group homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z_3$ to $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_7)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many group homomorphism from $\Bbb Z_3$ to $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_7)$?

**My attempt:** Since $\Bbb Z_3$ is cyclic, hence the homomorphisms are all determined by $\phi(\overline{1})$. On the other hand $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_7)\cong \Bbb Z_6$
.

Since $o(\phi(\overline{1}))\mid |\Bbb Z_3|$, so $o(\phi(\overline{1}))$ can only be $1,~3$. If the order is $1$, it means $\phi(\overline{1})=\overline{1}$. It is indeed a homo. If the order is $3$, it means $\phi(\overline{1})=\overline{2}$ or $\overline{4}$. So the total number of group homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z_3$ to $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_7)$ is three, as I show above. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, looks right

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z, \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)) = \operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z, C_6) = C_6[3] = \{e, g^2, g^4\}$$